# How to train AutoModelForQuestionAnswering model with Distribute Data Parallel?

Tags: pytorch, multiprocessing, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

I reproduce the training code from DataParallel to DistributedDataParallel, It does not release bugs in training, but it does not print any log or running.
Could show me what is wrong with my code?

This is my code and the distribute data parallel reference from https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/ddp_tutorial.html#basic-use-case

```
"""
    Usages:
        CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python train.py --train_config default_config --work_dir runs/train/layoutlmv2-base-uncased_50e/

"""

import argparse
from torch import distributed as dist
from transformers import AutoModelForQuestionAnswering
import torch.nn as nn
from utils import create_logger, get_gpu_memory_map, load_feature_from_file, setup, cleanup
from config import TRAIN_FEATURE_PATH, VAL_FEATURE_PATH, MODEL_CHECKPOINT, TRAINING_CONFIGs
import numpy as np
import torch
import os
os.environ["TOKENIZERS_PARALLELISM"] = "false"
from torch.nn.parallel import DistributedDataParallel as DDP
import torch.multiprocessing as mp


def train(rank, model, train_data, val_data, world_size,
        epochs, optimizer, lr, save_freq,
        eval_freq, work_dir):


    device = rank
    print("Running DDP with model parallel example on cuda:{} device".format(rank))
    # logger.info("Running DDP with model parallel example on cuda:{} device".format(rank))

    setup(rank, world_size)
    GPU_usage_before = get_gpu_memory_map()
    model = model.to(rank)
    model = DDP(model, device_ids=[rank], find_unused_parameters=True)
    gpus_usage = np.sum(get_gpu_memory_map() - GPU_usage_before)
    print("GPUs usages for model: {} Mb".format(gpus_usage))
    # logger.info("GPUs usages for model: {} Mb".format(gpus_usage))
    
    optimizer = optimizer(model.parameters(), lr=lr)

    model.train()

    min_valid_loss = np.inf
    idx = 1

    for epoch in range(1, epochs):

        print("Epoch {}/{}".format(epoch, epochs))
        
        # logger.info("Epoch {}/{}".format(epoch, epochs))
        
        train_loss = 0.0
        for _, train_batch in enumerate(train_data):

            input_ids         = train_batch["input_ids"].to(device)
            attention_mask    = train_batch["attention_mask"].to(device)
            token_type_ids    = train_batch["token_type_ids"].to(device)
            bbox              = train_batch["bbox"].to(device)
            image             = train_batch["image"].to(device)
            start_positions   = train_batch["start_positions"].to(device)
            end_positions     = train_batch["end_positions"].to(device)

            # zero the parameter gradients
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            # forward + backward + optimize
            outputs = model(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, token_type_ids=token_type_ids,
                            bbox=bbox, image=image, start_positions=start_positions, end_positions=end_positions)
    
            loss = outputs.loss
            
            loss.backward()
            
            optimizer.step()

            train_loss += loss.item()


            # Evaluate current model on entire validation dataset after each `eval_freq` iterations
            if idx % eval_freq == 1:
                val_loss = 0.0
                model.eval()
                for _, val_batch in enumerate(val_data):
                    
                    # val_batch               = val_batch.to(device)
                    input_ids               = val_batch["input_ids"].to(device)
                    attention_mask          = val_batch["attention_mask"].to(device)
                    token_type_ids          = val_batch["token_type_ids"].to(device)
                    bbox                    = val_batch["bbox"].to(device)
                    image                   = val_batch["image"].to(device)
                    start_positions         = val_batch["start_positions"].to(device)
                    end_positions           = val_batch["end_positions"].to(device)
                    
                    outputs = model(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, token_type_ids=token_type_ids,
                                bbox=bbox, image=image, start_positions=start_positions, end_positions=end_positions)
                    loss = outputs.loss
                    # Calculate Loss
                    val_loss += loss.item()
                
                print("Iterations: {:<6} - epoch: {:<3} - train_loss: {:<6} - val_loss: {:<6}".format(idx, epoch, train_loss/eval_freq, val_loss/len(val_data)))
                print("Iterations: {:<6} - epoch: {:<3} - train_loss: {:<6} - val_loss: {:<6}".format(idx, epoch, train_loss/eval_freq, val_loss/len(val_data)))

                # logger.info("Iterations: {:<6} - epoch: {:<3} - train_loss: {:<6} - val_loss: {:<6}".format(idx, epoch, train_loss/eval_freq, val_loss/len(val_data)))
                # loss_log.info("Iterations: {:<6} - epoch: {:<3} - train_loss: {:<6} - val_loss: {:<6}".format(idx, epoch, train_loss/eval_freq, val_loss/len(val_data)))

                    
                if min_valid_loss > val_loss/len(val_data):
                    print("Found best model !! Validation loss descreased from {} to {}".format(min_valid_loss, val_loss/len(val_data)))
                    # logger.info("Found best model !! Validation loss descreased from {} to {}".format(min_valid_loss, val_loss/len(val_data)))
                    torch.save(model.state_dict(), os.path.join(work_dir, 'best'+'.pth'))
                    min_valid_loss = val_loss/len(val_data)

                # Save model each save_freq iteration
                if idx % save_freq == 1:
                    print("Saving model to {}".format(os.path.join(work_dir, str(idx).zfill(5)+'.pth')))
                    # logger.info("Saving model to {}".format(os.path.join(work_dir, str(idx).zfill(5)+'.pth')))
                    torch.save(model.state_dict(), os.path.join(work_dir, str(idx).zfill(5)+'.pth'))
                    dist.barrier()

                # Reset training loss
                train_loss = 0.0
                
            idx += 1


    # logger.info("Done !")
    # logger.info("The minimum on validation {}".format(min_valid_loss))
    print("DONE !")
    print("The minimum on validation {}".format(min_valid_loss))

    cleanup()

    return model


def main(args):

    gpu_ids = [i for i in range(torch.cuda.device_count())]
    torch.cuda.set_device(gpu_ids[0])
    
    if not os.path.exists(args['work_dir']):
        os.mkdir(args['work_dir'])
    # Create logger
    loss_log = create_logger(os.path.join(args["work_dir"], 'loss.log'))
    logger = create_logger(os.path.join(args['work_dir'], 'log.log'))

    logger.info('Loading training configuration ...')
    config = TRAINING_CONFIGs[args['train_config']]
    optimizer, momentum, lr, epochs, batch_size,\
         eval_freq, save_freq, num_workers = config['optimizer'], config['momentum'], \
        config['lr'], config['epochs'], \
        config['batch_size'], config['eval_freq'], config['save_freq'], config['num_workers']
    logger.info("Configuration: {}".format(config))

    # Check whether feature path file existing or not
    if not os.path.exists(TRAIN_FEATURE_PATH):
        logger.error("Invalid training feature path")
        exit(0)
    if not os.path.exists(VAL_FEATURE_PATH):
        logger.error("Invalid validation feature path")
        exit(0)

    # Load data into program 
    logger.info("Loading training dataset from {} ...".format(TRAIN_FEATURE_PATH))
    train_dataloader = load_feature_from_file(path=TRAIN_FEATURE_PATH, 
                                            batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=num_workers)

    logger.info("Loading validation dataset from {} ...".format(VAL_FEATURE_PATH))
    val_dataloader = load_feature_from_file(path=VAL_FEATURE_PATH, 
                                            batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=num_workers)

    logger.info("Training size: {} - Validation size: {}".format(
        len(train_dataloader.dataset), len(val_dataloader.dataset)))

    logger.info("Loading pre-training model from {} checkpoint".format(MODEL_CHECKPOINT))
    model = AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained(MODEL_CHECKPOINT)
    
    # Fine-tuning model
    # trained_model = train(model=model, train_data=train_dataloader, val_data=val_dataloader,
    #                   epochs=epochs, optimizer=optimizer, lr=lr, loss_log=loss_log, save_freq=save_freq,
    #                     work_dir=args['work_dir'], logger=logger, eval_freq=eval_freq, gpu_ids=gpu_ids)

    mp.spawn(train,
             args=(model, train_dataloader, val_dataloader, len(gpu_ids), 
                   epochs, optimizer, lr, save_freq,
                   eval_freq, args['work_dir']),
             nprocs=len(gpu_ids),
             join=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Fine tuning pre-training model on DocVQA data')

    parser.add_argument('--work_dir', default='runs/train/train_1/',
        help='The directory store model checkpoint and log file',
    )

    parser.add_argument('--train_config', default='default_config', 
        help='The training configurations: learning rate, batch size, epochs, optimizer, ...'
    )

    args = vars(parser.parse_args())

    main(args)
```

**The output in terminal like below.**

```sh
(transformer_env)root@ae94a4e6c92d:/mlcv/WorkingSpace/NCKH/tiennv/vqa_thesis/docvqa/libs/layoutlmv2# CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1,2 python train.py --work_dir ./runs/train/test_multi-gpus --train_config default_config
2021-09-26 10:11:49,801 - INFO - Loading training configuration ...
2021-09-26 10:11:49,802 - INFO - Configuration: {'optimizer': <class 'torch.optim.adam.Adam'>, 'lr': 0.0001, 'epochs': 2, 'batch_size': 2, 'momentum': 0.9, 'eval_freq': 1, 'save_freq': 1, 'num_workers': 4}
2021-09-26 10:11:49,803 - INFO - Loading training dataset from /mlcv/Databases/DocVQA_2020-21/task_1/extracted_features/layoutlmv2/train ...
2021-09-26 10:11:49,953 - INFO - Loading validation dataset from /mlcv/Databases/DocVQA_2020-21/task_1/extracted_features/layoutlmv2/val ...
2021-09-26 10:11:49,977 - INFO - Training size: 39456 - Validation size: 5344
2021-09-26 10:11:49,978 - INFO - Loading pre-training model from microsoft/layoutlmv2-base-uncased checkpoint
Some weights of the model checkpoint at microsoft/layoutlmv2-base-uncased were not used when initializing LayoutLMv2ForQuestionAnswering: ['layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.0.conv1.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.7.conv1.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.11.conv2.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.12.conv2.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.5.conv2.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.19.conv3.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.1.conv3.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.15.conv2.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res3.1.conv2.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.19.conv1.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res2.0.conv3.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res5.0.conv2.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.21.conv1.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res5.2.conv3.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.16.conv2.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.21.conv2.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.14.conv3.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.2.conv2.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.8.conv1.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res3.2.conv3.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.9.conv2.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.4.conv1.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res2.2.conv1.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.22.conv2.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res5.0.conv3.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.5.conv1.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res3.3.conv3.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res2.2.conv3.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.4.conv2.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.17.conv1.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res3.1.conv1.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.11.conv1.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.1.conv2.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.3.conv1.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.7.conv3.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.8.conv2.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res3.3.conv1.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.13.conv1.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.22.conv3.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res5.2.conv1.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res5.0.shortcut.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res2.2.conv2.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.6.conv2.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res5.1.conv1.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res3.2.conv2.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.13.conv3.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res2.0.conv1.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res2.0.conv2.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.5.conv3.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.20.conv1.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.16.conv3.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.0.conv2.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.7.conv2.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.14.conv1.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.11.conv3.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res2.1.conv2.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res3.3.conv2.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.2.conv3.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.3.conv2.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.12.conv1.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.20.conv3.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res5.0.conv1.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.3.conv3.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.14.conv2.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.10.conv3.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res3.0.conv2.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.18.conv1.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.19.conv2.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.21.conv3.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.stem.conv1.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.17.conv3.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.0.conv3.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.12.conv3.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.1.conv1.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res5.2.conv2.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res3.0.conv3.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.8.conv3.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res2.1.conv3.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.0.shortcut.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.22.conv1.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res3.1.conv3.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res3.2.conv1.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.15.conv1.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res3.0.conv1.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res5.1.conv2.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res2.1.conv1.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.9.conv1.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.18.conv3.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.10.conv2.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.20.conv2.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.17.conv2.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.18.conv2.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.10.conv1.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.6.conv1.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res3.0.shortcut.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.6.conv3.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.16.conv1.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.2.conv1.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res5.1.conv3.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.4.conv3.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.9.conv3.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.13.conv2.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res2.0.shortcut.norm.num_batches_tracked', 'layoutlmv2.visual.backbone.bottom_up.res4.15.conv3.norm.num_batches_tracked']
- This IS expected if you are initializing LayoutLMv2ForQuestionAnswering from the checkpoint of a model trained on another task or with another architecture (e.g. initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForPreTraining model).
- This IS NOT expected if you are initializing LayoutLMv2ForQuestionAnswering from the checkpoint of a model that you expect to be exactly identical (initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForSequenceClassification model).
Some weights of LayoutLMv2ForQuestionAnswering were not initialized from the model checkpoint at microsoft/layoutlmv2-base-uncased and are newly initialized: ['qa_outputs.weight', 'qa_outputs.bias', 'layoutlmv2.visual_segment_embedding']
You should probably TRAIN this model on a down-stream task to be able to use it for predictions and inference.
Running DDP with model parallel example on cuda:0 device
Running DDP with model parallel example on cuda:1 device
GPUs usages for model: 6721 Mb
Epoch 1/2
GPUs usages for model: 6721 Mb
Epoch 1/2
```

It still prints anything ...
Please help me ...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.